# Converting row data to column without Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Attribute table having multiple of data.

I am  giving simple example

I have a table with the following data:-

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>ROLL NO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>StockNumber</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Keyword</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>

    </body>
  </html>
```

`I want to show following output:-`

```html
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>StockNumber</td>
     <td>Keyword</td>
  </tr>
 
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want show row data (i.e:- `Description`, `StockNumber`, `Keyword`) as column without using `Pivot` and dynamically.
Is there any other way to show row data as column , dynamically

Comment: Are there only 5 rows?

Comment: @FelixPamittan:- Their might be more rows..

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the below code.Its working in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Attribute TABLE(
    ID      INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO @Attribute VALUES
(1, 'Description'), 
(2, 'StockNumber'),
(3, 'Price'),
(4, 'Logo'), 
(5, 'Diagram');

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Description' THEN ID END) AS Description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'StockNumber' THEN ID END) AS StockNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Price' THEN ID END) AS Price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Logo' THEN ID END) AS Logo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Diagram' THEN ID END) AS Diagram
FROM (
  SELECT Name,ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
FROM @Attribute) AS t
GROUP BY rn
```

Comment: :- Actually i aready have table having those  rows. I need only query for showing row as column.

Comment: You mean to say that you required the names as comma separated in a row?

Comment: :- Actually i need to show all row data should display as column name (Not comma seperated)

Comment: Replace the table name in my query with your table name. If you have more name field, you need to pass them dynamically.

Comment: :- But you are using aggregate function. I want to display all records, dynamically. Is there any way to show rows as column without using `CASE` or without `aggregate function`, dynamically